"Connection lost: EOF; connection lost before Subscribe completed" when connecting to AWS IoT Core through proxy with MQTT Paho in Golang
I've been struggling to connect to the AWS IoT Core MQTT broker with a Golang application running the Paho library through a Tinyproxy proxy instance running on localhost:3128 without success.
I was able to manage this kind of situation in Python using aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2 but unfortunately the aws-sdk-v2 for Golang doesn't have support for IoT Core yet, so I've been trying to solve this with Paho.
This is my main function
import (
    MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

func MainFunc() {
    MQTT.DEBUG = log.New(os.Stdout, "", 0)
    MQTT.ERROR = log.New(os.Stderr, "", 0)

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    basePassword := `mypassword`
    server := flag.String("server", "ssl://iot.customdomain.io:443", "The full URL of the MQTT server to connect to")
    topic := flag.String("topic", "test/foo", "Topic to subscribe to")
    qos := flag.Int("qos", 0, "The QoS to subscribe to messages at")
    clientid := flag.String("clientid", "my-gw", "A clientid for the connection")
    username := flag.String("username", "CertificateAuth&my-user?x-amz-customauthorizer-name=iot-custom-authorizer", "A username to authenticate to the MQTT server")
    password := flag.String("password", basePassword, "Password to match username")
    token := flag.String("token", "", "An optional token credential to authenticate with")
    // skipVerify := flag.Bool("skipVerify", false, "Controls whether TLS certificate is verified")
    flag.Parse()

    os.Setenv("ALL_PROXY", fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%s", "3128"))
    defer os.Unsetenv("ALL_PROXY")

    connOpts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().AddBroker(*server).
        SetClientID(*clientid).
        SetCleanSession(true).
        SetProtocolVersion(4)
    if *username != "" {
        connOpts.SetUsername(*username)
        if *password != "" {
            connOpts.SetPassword(*password)
        }
    } else if *token != "" {
        connOpts.SetCredentialsProvider(func() (string, string) {
            return "unused", *token
        })
    }
    connOpts.SetHTTPHeaders(http.Header{
        "x-amz-customauthorizer-name": {"iot-custom-authorizer"},
        "Proxy-Connection":            {"keep-alive"},
    })

    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(AmazonRootCA1Cert))
    TlsCerts := TlsCerts{
        IotPrivateKey:     IotPrivateKey,
        IotCertificatePem: IotCertificatePem,
        AlnpProtocols:     []string{"mqtt", "x-amzn-mqtt-ca"},
    }
    tlsConfig := parseTlsConfig(TlsCerts)
    connOpts.SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)

    connOpts.OnConnect = func(c MQTT.Client) {
        if token := c.Subscribe(*topic, byte(*qos), onMessageReceived); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            fmt.Println(token.Error())
        }
    }

    // Illustrates customized TLS configuration prior to connection attempt
    connOpts.OnConnectAttempt = func(broker *url.URL, tlsCfg *tls.Config) *tls.Config {
        cfg := tlsCfg.Clone()
        cfg.ServerName = broker.Hostname()
        return cfg
    }
    dialer := proxy.FromEnvironment()
    connOpts.SetCustomOpenConnectionFn(func(uri *url.URL, options MQTT.ClientOptions) (net.Conn, error) {
        fmt.Printf("Custom dialer invoked for %s\n", uri.Host) // Debug log for verification
        address := uri.Host

        return dialer.Dial(uri.Scheme, address)
    })

    client := MQTT.NewClient(connOpts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Connected to %s\n", *server)
    }

    <-c
}


The username and password there are to be passed to a custom authorizer lambda function running in front of the IoT Core MQTT broker.
As stated by the paho lib implementation with http proxies, here's my Dial implementation for the dialer also with the related mqtt stuff.
type httpProxy struct {
    host     string
    haveAuth bool
    username string
    password string
    forward  proxy.Dialer
}

func (s httpProxy) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("HTTP proxy dialer for %s", s.host)
}

func newHTTPProxy(uri *url.URL, forward proxy.Dialer) (proxy.Dialer, error) {
    s := new(httpProxy)
    s.host = uri.Host
    s.forward = forward
    if uri.User != nil {
        s.haveAuth = true
        s.username = uri.User.Username()
        s.password, _ = uri.User.Password()
    }

    return s, nil
}

func (s *httpProxy) Dial(_, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    reqURL := url.URL{
        Scheme: "https",
        Host:   addr,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("CONNECT", reqURL.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Close = false
    if s.haveAuth {
        req.SetBasicAuth(s.username, s.password)
    }
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "paho.mqtt")

    // Dial and create the client connection.
    c, err := s.forward.Dial("tcp", s.host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = req.Write(c)
    if err != nil {
        _ = c.Close()
        return nil, err
    }

    resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(c), req)
    if err != nil {
        _ = c.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    _ = resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        _ = c.Close()
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("proxied connection returned an error: %v", resp.Status)
    }
    TlsCerts := TlsCerts{
        IotPrivateKey:     IotPrivateKey,
        IotCertificatePem: IotCertificatePem,
        AlnpProtocols:     []string{"mqtt", "x-amzn-mqtt-ca"},
    }
    tlsConfig := parseTlsConfig(TlsCerts)
        // Tunnel the communication over TLS
    tlsConn := tls.Client(c, tlsConfig)

    return tlsConn, nil
}

func init() {
    // Pre-register custom HTTP proxy dialers for use with proxy.FromEnvironment
    proxy.RegisterDialerType("http", newHTTPProxy)
    proxy.RegisterDialerType("https", newHTTPProxy)
}

func onMessageReceived(client MQTT.Client, message MQTT.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("Received message on topic: %s\n", message.Topic())
    fmt.Printf("Message: %s\n", message.Payload())
}

var messagePubHandler MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    fmt.Println("Received message on topic: " + msg.Topic())
    ProcessMessage(msg.Payload())
}

func ProcessMessage(payload []byte) {
    fmt.Println(string(payload))
}

Running the code above with the logs enabled I see this error of the title, where the connection is being lost before the subscribe step is completed.
[client]   Connect()
[store]    memorystore initialized
[client]   about to write new connect msg
[client]   using custom onConnectAttempt handler...
Custom dialer invoked for iot.customdomain.io:443
[client]   socket connected to broker
[client]   Using MQTT 3.1.1 protocol
[net]      connect started
[net]      received connack
[client]   startCommsWorkers called
[client]   client is connected/reconnected
[net]      incoming started
[net]      startIncomingComms started
[net]      outgoing started
[net]      startComms started
[client]   enter Subscribe
[client]   startCommsWorkers done
[client]   exit startClient
[pinger]   keepalive starting
Connected to ssl://iot.customdomain.io:443
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      logic waiting for msg on ibound
[net]      startIncomingComms: inboundFromStore complete
[net]      logic waiting for msg on ibound
[client]   SUBSCRIBE: dup: false qos: 1 retain: false rLength: 0 MessageID: 1 topics: [test/foo]
[client]   sending subscribe message, topic: test/foo
[client]   exit Subscribe
[net]      obound priority msg to write, type *packets.SubscribePacket
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      incoming complete
[net]      startIncomingComms: got msg on ibound
[net]      logic waiting for msg on ibound
[net]      startIncomingComms: ibound complete
[net]      startIncomingComms goroutine complete
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[client]   Connect comms goroutine - error triggered EOF
[client]   internalConnLost called
[client]   stopCommsWorkers called
[pinger]   keepalive stopped
[router]   matchAndDispatch exiting
[client]   startCommsWorkers output redirector finished
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      outgoing comms stopping
[client]   stopCommsWorkers waiting for workers
[client]   stopCommsWorkers waiting for comms
[client]   internalConnLost waiting on workers
[net]      startComms closing outError
[client]   incoming comms goroutine done
[client]   stopCommsWorkers done
[client]   internalConnLost workers stopped
[msgids]   cleaned up subs
[client]   internalConnLost complete
connection lost before Subscribe completed
[client]   enter reconnect
[client]   about to write new connect msg
[client]   using custom onConnectAttempt handler...
Custom dialer invoked for iot.customdomain.io:443
Connection lost: EOF
[client]   socket connected to broker
[client]   Using MQTT 3.1.1 protocol
[net]      connect started
[net]      received connack
[client]   startCommsWorkers called
[client]   client is connected/reconnected
[net]      incoming started
[net]      startIncomingComms started
[net]      outgoing started
[net]      startComms started
[pinger]   keepalive starting
[client]   startCommsWorkers done
[store]    enter Resume
[store]    exit resume
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      logic waiting for msg on ibound
[net]      startIncomingComms: inboundFromStore complete
[net]      logic waiting for msg on ibound
[client]   enter Subscribe
[client]   SUBSCRIBE: dup: false qos: 1 retain: false rLength: 0 MessageID: 2 topics: [test/foo]
[client]   sending subscribe message, topic: test/foo
[client]   exit Subscribe
[net]      obound priority msg to write, type *packets.SubscribePacket
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      incoming complete
[net]      startIncomingComms: got msg on ibound
[net]      logic waiting for msg on ibound
[net]      startIncomingComms: ibound complete
[net]      startIncomingComms goroutine complete
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[client]   Connect comms goroutine - error triggered EOF
[client]   internalConnLost called
[client]   stopCommsWorkers called
[router]   matchAndDispatch exiting
[client]   startCommsWorkers output redirector finished
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[net]      outgoing comms stopping
[net]      startComms closing outError
[client]   incoming comms goroutine done
[pinger]   keepalive stopped
[client]   stopCommsWorkers waiting for workers
[client]   stopCommsWorkers waiting for comms
[client]   stopCommsWorkers done
[client]   internalConnLost waiting on workers
[client]   internalConnLost workers stopped
[msgids]   cleaned up subs
[client]   internalConnLost complete
Connection lost: EOF
connection lost before Subscribe completed
[client]   enter reconnect
[client]   Detect continual connection lost after reconnect, slept for 1 seconds
[client]   about to write new connect msg
...
[client]   internalConnLost complete
Connection lost: EOF
connection lost before Subscribe completed
[client]   enter reconnect
panic: test timed out after 30s
    running tests:
        TestClientConnectWithTlsToIoTCoreCloudBrokerThroughProxy (30s)

The error continues looping until the TestClientConnectWithTlsToIoTCoreCloudBrokerThroughProxy test fails due to a timeout error.
I can also see the tinyproxy logs establishing the connection and closing it
CONNECT   Nov 10 16:52:53.777 [45157]: Connect (file descriptor 4): 127.0.0.1
CONNECT   Nov 10 16:52:53.777 [45157]: Request (file descriptor 4): CONNECT iot.customdomain.io:443 HTTP/1.1
INFO      Nov 10 16:52:53.778 [45157]: No upstream proxy for iot.customdomain.io
INFO      Nov 10 16:52:53.778 [45157]: opensock: opening connection to iot.customdomain.io:443
INFO      Nov 10 16:52:53.920 [45157]: opensock: getaddrinfo returned for iot.customdomain.io:443
CONNECT   Nov 10 16:52:54.098 [45157]: Established connection to host "iot.customdomain.io" using file descriptor 8.
INFO      Nov 10 16:52:54.098 [45157]: Not sending client headers to remote machine
INFO      Nov 10 16:52:54.841 [45157]: Closed connection between local client (fd:4) and remote client (fd:8)

So I am not able to make a working connection to IoT Core using Golang Paho through a proxy and I have no idea on what's going on.

If the connection is getting dropped as the result of sending a subscription this probably means the client is not authorised to subscribe to that topic

Thanks for the answer. Actually, this was one of the issues indeed, but the code had other problems as I mentioned in the answer below.

After @hardillb answer, I realized that, indeed, the client was not authorized to subscribe to that topic, but another connection issue was happening. After a couple of attempts to make the code work, finally I came up with a solution that was capable of connecting to the IoT Core MQTT broker instance, publishing and subscribing to that topic, and receiving the message. This is the working code.
import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"

    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"

    MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

type TlsCerts struct {
    IotPrivateKey     string
    IotCertificatePem string
    CaCertificatePem  string
    AlnpProtocols     []string
}

type Config struct {
    ClientId  string
    BrokerUrl string
    TlsCerts  TlsCerts
}

type httpProxy struct {
    host     string
    haveAuth bool
    username string
    password string
    forward  proxy.Dialer
}

func parseTlsConfig(tlsCerts TlsCerts) *tls.Config {
    if tlsCerts.IotPrivateKey == "" || tlsCerts.IotCertificatePem == "" {
        return nil
    }

    cert := parseTlsCertificates(tlsCerts)

    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(AmazonRootCA1Cert))

    return &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            caCertPool,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
        NextProtos:         tlsCerts.AlnpProtocols,
        ServerName:         "iot.customdomain.io",
    }
}

func parseTlsCertificates(
    tlsCerts TlsCerts,
) tls.Certificate {
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(tlsCerts.IotPrivateKey))
    if block == nil {

        log.Panic("Failed to parse private key")

    }

    var key interface{}
    var err error

    key, err = x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        key, err = x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicf("Failed to parse private key: %v", err)
        }

        switch k := key.(type) {
        case *rsa.PrivateKey:
            key = k
        case *ecdsa.PrivateKey:
            key = k
        default:
            log.Panicf("Unsupported private key type: %T", key)
        }
    }

    block, _ = pem.Decode([]byte(tlsCerts.IotCertificatePem))
    if block == nil {
        log.Panic("Failed to parse certificate")
    }
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("Failed to parse certificate: %v", err)
    }

    return tls.Certificate{
        PrivateKey:  key,
        Certificate: [][]byte{cert.Raw},
    }
}

func (s httpProxy) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("HTTP proxy dialer for %s", s.host)
}

func newHTTPProxy(uri *url.URL, forward proxy.Dialer) (proxy.Dialer, error) {
    s := new(httpProxy)
    s.host = uri.Host
    s.forward = forward
    if uri.User != nil {
        s.haveAuth = true
        s.username = uri.User.Username()
        s.password, _ = uri.User.Password()
    }

    return s, nil
}

func (s *httpProxy) Dial(_, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    reqURL := url.URL{
        Scheme: "https",
        Host:   addr,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("CONNECT", reqURL.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Close = false
    if s.haveAuth {
        req.SetBasicAuth(s.username, s.password)
    }
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "paho.mqtt")

    // Dial and create the client connection.
    c, err := s.forward.Dial("tcp", s.host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = req.Write(c)
    if err != nil {
        _ = c.Close()
        return nil, err
    }

    resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(c), req)
    if err != nil {
        _ = c.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    _ = resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        _ = c.Close()
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("proxied connection returned an error: %v", resp.Status)
    }
    TlsCerts := TlsCerts{
        IotPrivateKey:     IotPrivateKey,
        IotCertificatePem: IotCertificatePem,
        AlnpProtocols:     []string{"mqtt", "x-amzn-mqtt-ca"},
    }
    tlsConfig := parseTlsConfig(TlsCerts)

    tlsConn := tls.Client(c, tlsConfig)

    return tlsConn, nil
}

func init() {
    // Pre-register custom HTTP proxy dialers for use with proxy.FromEnvironment
    proxy.RegisterDialerType("http", newHTTPProxy)
    proxy.RegisterDialerType("https", newHTTPProxy)
}

func onMessageReceived(client MQTT.Client, message MQTT.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("Received message on topic: %s\n", message.Topic())
    fmt.Printf("Message: %s\n", message.Payload())
}

var messagePubHandler MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    fmt.Println("Received message on topic: " + msg.Topic())
    ProcessMessage(msg.Payload())
}

func ProcessMessage(payload []byte) {
    fmt.Println(string(payload))
}

func MainFunc() {
    MQTT.DEBUG = log.New(os.Stdout, "", 0)
    MQTT.ERROR = log.New(os.Stderr, "", 0)

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    server := "https://iot.customdomain.io:443"
    topic := "right/topic/now"
    qos := 0
    clientid := "my-client-id"

    os.Setenv("ALL_PROXY", fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%s", "3128"))
    defer os.Unsetenv("ALL_PROXY")

    connOpts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().AddBroker(server).
        SetClientID(clientid).
        SetCleanSession(true).
        SetProtocolVersion(4)

    connOpts.OnConnect = func(c MQTT.Client) {
        if token := c.Subscribe(topic, byte(qos), onMessageReceived); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            fmt.Println(token.Error())
        }

        text := `{"message": "Hello MQTT"}`
        token := c.Publish(topic, byte(qos), false, text)
        token.Wait()
    }

    dialer := proxy.FromEnvironment()
    connOpts.SetCustomOpenConnectionFn(func(uri *url.URL, options MQTT.ClientOptions) (net.Conn, error) {
        fmt.Printf("Custom dialer invoked for %s\n", uri.Host) // Debug log for verification
        address := uri.Host
        return dialer.Dial(uri.Scheme, address)
    })

    client := MQTT.NewClient(connOpts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Connected to %s\n", server)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Disconnecting")
    client.Disconnect(250)
    fmt.Println("Exiting")
}

A lot of stuff changed like the removal of the SetUsername and the SetPassword calls since I am already authenticating via certificates and private key.
This was removed as well:
connOpts.OnConnectAttempt = func(broker *url.URL, tlsCfg *tls.Config) *tls.Config {
        cfg := tlsCfg.Clone()
        cfg.ServerName = broker.Hostname()
        return cfg
    }

Apparently, the previous code was a complete mess, so there were a lot of issues, not only one issue, but one of those issues was exactly the problem if the lack of authorization for that specific topic. But the code above is capable of connecting to IoT Core through a Tinyproxy instance running on the localhost.
